# DELETE http://localhost:8080/patients undefined 404 ()

Tags: spring-boot, ionic3

I'm creating h RestApi service through spring-boot when calling this API through ionic it gives me an error DELETE http://localhost:8080/patientsundefined 404 (), here is my code:
 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/patientsundefined", ok: false…}

```
#ts
deletePatient(Patient_add:Patient){

    this.databasedata.deletePatient(Patient_add).subscribe(

      (data:any)=>{

        if(data.affectedRows==1){
           let mes=this._toast.create({
            message:'Task Deleted Successfully',
            duration:2000,
            position:'bottom'
          });

          this.AllPatient.splice(this.AllPatient.indexOf(Patient_add),1);
          mes.present();
        }

        else{
          let mes=this._toast.create({
            message:'Error in deleting task',
            duration:2000,
            position:'bottom'
          });
          mes.present();
        }
      }
  ,)}



#.html
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list inset>
    <ion-input type="hidden" placeholder="id" autofocus="" [(ngModel)]="id" ></ion-input>
    <ion-input placeholder="Write here your name"  [(ngModel)]="name"  ></ion-input>
    <ion-input placeholder="Write here your doctor name"  [(ngModel)]="doctor_name"  ></ion-input>
    <ion-input placeholder="Write here your Hosptial or clinic name"  [(ngModel)]="hospital_clinic"  ></ion-input>
    <ion-input placeholder="Write date or your prescription?"  [(ngModel)]="date" ></ion-input>

<ion-buttons>
  <button (click)= "addPatient()"> ADD</button>
</ion-buttons>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let AP of AllPatient" >

      <ion-label [ngClass]="{'donestatus': AP.Status=='done','pendingstatus':AP.Status=='pending'}" >{{AP.name}} {{AP.doctor_name}} {{AP.hospital_clinic}} {{AP.date}}</ion-label>
      <ion-icon item-right (click)="deletePatient(AP)"  ios="ios-trash" md="md-trash"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon item-right (click)="updatePatient(AP)"  ios="ios-color-wand" md="md-color-wand"></ion-icon>
      <!--<ion-icon name="trash" ios="ios-trash" md="md-trash"></ion-icon>-->
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>


</ion-content>


#provider.ts
deletePatient(item:Patient){
    return this.http.delete(this.url+item.Id, httpOptions)

  }

#.Controller(Spring-boot)


@RequestMapping(value = "patients/{id}", method = {RequestMethod.DELETE})
    public ResponseEntity<Void> delete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        try {
            service.deletePatient(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please modify the URL which you invoke the service as follows:
`this.http.delete(this.url+'/'+item.Id, httpOptions)` due to you defined the URI of your deletion service is `patients/{id}`.

Second, it seems that the ID you passed to service is undefined, you should also check this.

Good luck!